# Why are official ELPA repositories not accessible from within China Mainland

Tags: emacs, elpa, melpa

I am setting up my archlinux-desktop in mainland China. While configuring ELPA for emacs, it turned out that (at least) the following archives are not available:

```
(setq package-archives '(
    ("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
    ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
```

Reason: Connections cannot be established and are aborted

---

On https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA I found a remark:

> Emacs users in China mainland can use popkit.org
>   (http://elpa.popkit.org/) archive:

```
 (add-to-list 'package-archives '("popkit" . "http://elpa.popkit.org/packages/"))
```

In addition I found basically all relevant (and more) repositories on http://elpa.emacs-china.org/

```
ELPA                   | 镜像地址
-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------
GNU ELPA               | http://elpa.emacs-china.org/gnu/
MELPA                  | http://elpa.emacs-china.org/melpa/
MELPA Stable           | http://elpa.emacs-china.org/melpa-stable/
Marmalade              | http://elpa.emacs-china.org/marmalade/
Org                    | http://elpa.emacs-china.org/org/
Sunrise Commander ELPA | http://elpa.emacs-china.org/sunrise-commander/
user42 ELPA            | http://elpa.emacs-china.org/user42/
```

---

This brings two questions:
- Why are the official repositories not accessible from within China?
- Is it secure to download from these sources?

Comment: Technically, IIUC they're not available because China's firewall blocks them.  As for why, you'd have to ask those who control that firewall.

Comment: On my first attempt on setting up Archlinux from chinese mirrors the crypto packages of group base failed to install due to failed checksum tests. Being unable to download these things from beyond Chinas Great Firewall makes me a bit suspicious. Is there a way to check the sources provided by chinese "mirrors" are the same as on the official places?